# How do I manage the per web request scoping for an Asp.Net Core app when I share Ninject modules that are already used by several other apps?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, ninject

I have a bigger consisting of shared libraries and different host applications.

[image]

For now I have bindings like:

```
Bind<IUserService>().To<AspNetUserService>().InScope(RequestScope);
```

Or:

```
Bind<IConfig>().To<Config>().InHttpContextOrThreadScope()
```

`InHttpContextOrThreadScope` is an extension method:

```
public static IBindingNamedWithOrOnSyntax<T> InHttpContextOrThreadScope<T>(this IBindingInSyntax<T> bindingInSyntax)
{
   return bindingInSyntax.InScope(context => HttpContext.Current ?? Thread.CurrentThread as object);
}
```

---

- How do I scope my applications for Asp.Net Core?
- How do I manage all the different scopings with my exisiting `NinjectModules` without breaking the old applications?

Comment: This [example project](https://github.com/dotnetjunkie/Missing-Core-DI-Extensions/tree/master/src/SampleApplication.Ninject) might give you some ideas. Especially take a look at how a `DisposableObject` [is used in the Startup](https://github.com/dotnetjunkie/Missing-Core-DI-Extensions/blob/master/src/SampleApplication.Ninject/Startup.cs#L45) class by making use of an [AsyncLocal](https://github.com/dotnetjunkie/Missing-Core-DI-Extensions/blob/master/src/SampleApplication.Ninject/Startup.cs#L19).

Comment: @Steven Thank you for your respone. Seems like you are everywhere =). In this example project I see how I can build a new project with Asp.Net Core, but not how to integrate this with an existing solution. Do I need to use AsyncLocal for all of my projects or do I need something like a HybridScope (Thread, HttpContext, AsyncLocal)? I am not familar with AsyncLocal so far :/

Comment: Hi Rookian, I'm certainly not everywhere, just in the DI space :). AsyncLocal is quite simple. AsyncLocal can be seen as a 'request local', i.e. it flows with asynchronous method calls within a single web request, but each request will have its own value. Ninject is very flexible. As you can see in my example, within a few lines of code you will have a lifestyle similar to the `AsyncScopedLifestyle` that Simple Injector uses for handling ASP.NET core web requests.

Comment: What you should do is configure an `Func<IContext, object>` method in each Composition Root (like this [RequestScope](https://github.com/dotnetjunkie/Missing-Core-DI-Extensions/blob/master/src/SampleApplication.Ninject/Startup.cs#L23) method) and pass it on to your application's Ninject Modules. This way they can use that delegate to make their 'request scoped' registrations, without knowing what scope is actually used.